# What does 'august clan' mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I encountered it on Theogony of Hesiod on verse 44. I don't have any idea of my own. Anything is very appreciated.

Comment: Try a dictionary. Hint: when you have more than one word, you can look them up separately.

Comment: honorable family

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster could have found the answer in any general-reference dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Context:  ***celebrate the [august clan](https://msu.edu/~tyrrell/theogon.pdf) of the gods
in song***, Theogony of Hesiod, line 44

*[Clan](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clan)* has connotations of *family* or *tribe*. MW:

> a group of people tracing descent from a common ancestor

[August](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/august) in this sense (with the stress on the second syllable!) means worthy of honour or respect. Again from MW:

> marked by majestic dignity or grandeur

So *august clan* here means something similar to **dignified family**.

Answer (score -1):

*[August](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/august#Etymology_1)* can mean *noble* or *majestic*. So, without the sentence I would assume it means something like *noble clan* or *venerable tribe* or something like that.

Comment: DV for answering a question that shows no research by the OP.

Comment: Your dictionary source (Wiktionary) provides two definitions and four synonyms for _august_: "**1.** Awe-inspiring, majestic, noble, venerable. [example:] an august patron of the arts **2.** Of noble birth. [example:] an august lineage". If you included that more complete wording in your answer, I would upvote the answer—because your final sentence seems quite accurate. I understand the theory behind downvoting accurate answers to "bad" questions, but I think the better approach is to delete the bad question. Also, why downvote one such answer but not the other one (posted 6 minutes later)?

Comment: @Sven Hi. I support downvotes to answers whose only source is Wiktionary when a plethora of professionally compiled dictionaries is available. I haven't DVed this answer because the question is closed.

Comment: @Knotell: Undoubtedly, Charl E's answer would be superior to Gulliver's even if Gulliver added the full Wictionary definition of _august_. And if the downvote had been cast on grounds that Wiktionary is an inferior resource, I would have thought, "Hmm. Okay." But the actual reason given for the downvote is that the question is bad, and I don't see why that rationale applies to the goose but not to the gander here. Also, as I said in my first comment, I disagree with the idea of punishing answerers—regardless of the legitimacy of their answers—as a strategy for dealing with bad questions.

Comment: In defense of @AndyT he (or possibly she?) is not the only one who downvotes answers to extremely poor-written questions.

Comment: @SvenYargs - The rationale for downvoting one and not the other is that the other didn't exist at the time. It appears Charl E's answer appeared twenty seconds after my comment. Charl E now has a downvote too.

Comment: @AndyT: I applaud your consistent application of what I consider a flawed rationale. (And I have upvoted Charl E's answer, although I expect a moderator to delete the question and answers in the fullness of time.)